# C++ design issue. New to templates

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to c++ templates.

I have a class whose constructor takes two arguments. It's a class that keeps a list of data -- it's actually a list of moves in a chess program.

I need to keep my original class as it's used in other places, but I now need to pass extra arguments to the class, and in doing so have a few extra private data members and specialize only one of the private methods -- everything else will stay the same. I don't think a derived class helps me here, as they aren't going to be similar objects, and also the private methods are called by the constructor and it will call the virtual method of the base class -- not the derived method.

So I guess templates are going to be my answer. Just looking for any hints about how might proceed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a job for composition.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is wrong.   Templates are no more the answer for your problem than inheritance is.

As jtbandes said in comment below your question, use composition.

Create another class that contains an instance of your existing class as a member.   Forward or delegate operations to that contained object as needed (i.e. a member function in your new class calls member functions of the contained object).   Add other members as needed, and operations to work with them.

Write your new code to interact with the new class.   When your new code needs to interact with your old code, pass the contained object (or a reference or a pointer to it) as needed.

You might choose to implement the container as a template, but that is an implementation choice, and depends on how you wish to reuse your container.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are used when you want to pass **at compile time** parameter like values,typenames, or classes. Templates are used when you want to use exactly the same class with the same methods, but applying it to different parameters. The case you described is not this I think.

If they aren't goign to be similar objects you may want to create a specialized class (or collections of function) to use from the various other classes.

Moreover you can think of creating a base class and extending it as needed. Using a virtual private method should allow you to select the method implementation of the object at runtime instead of the method of the base class.

We may help you more if you specify what does they need to share, what does your classes have in common?

Answer (score 0):

The bare bones of my present code looks like this:

```
class move_list{  
public:
  move_list(const position& pos, unsigned char ply):pos_(pos),ply_(ply){

  //Calculates moves and calls add_moves(ply,target_bitboard,flags)  for    each move

  }  

 //Some access functions etc...

  private:  
     //private variables
     void add_moves(char,Bitboard,movflags);
};
```

Add_moves places the moves on a vector in no particular order as they are generated. My new class however, is exactly the same except it requires extra data:

```
move_list(const position& pos, unsigned char ply,trans_table& TT,killers& kill,history& hist):pos_(pos),ply_(ply),TT_(TT),kill_(kill),hist_(hist) {
```

and the function add_moves needs to be changed to use the extra data to place the moves in order as it receives them. Everything else is the same. I guess I could just write an extra method to sort the list after they have all been generated, but from previous experience, sorting the list as it receives it has been quicker.